# How to make a GridLayout with CardViews scrollable in Android without the cards ending up overstretched?

Tags: android, scrollview, grid-layout, cardview

I have pretty much described the problem in the question itself.
I want to make the view scrollable, but by doing so everything gets super stretched out, which I don't want. I assume that the problem lies within the layout_height attributes and I've tried setting different ones to different values (match_parent, wrap_content, 0dp, even random integer dp) but nothing seems to work. I also tried adding a bunch of CardViews and that shrinks them but it doesn't shrink the RelativeLayout where the title is. (I will attach screenshots so you guys can see what's going on).  [Here's how it looks now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAaS2.png) [How it looks when I scroll down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xClZg.png) [How it looked when I added a lot CardViews.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1wOO.png)

Thank you in advance

Here is the code. (It seems long because it's repetitive)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HowAreYou">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:background="@drawable/background2">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:text="Симптоми"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#d76b73"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="4"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_cough"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/cough"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Кашлица"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_headache"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/headache"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Главоболка"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_fever"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/fever"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Покачена температура"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_stuffynose"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stuffynose"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Затнат нос"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_sorethroat"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"
                        tools:ignore="OnClick" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/sorethroat"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Болки во грлото"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_fatigue"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"
                        tools:ignore="OnClick" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/fatigue"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Замор"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_nausea"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/nausea"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Повраќање"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_stomachache"
                        android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/stomachache"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                        android:text="Болки во стомакот"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            
        </GridLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/howareyou_continue_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
                android:text="Продолжи"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cardview replace the layout_height from '0dp' to wrap_content

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I did what you suggested. Didn't solve it on it's own but I also replaced every 0dp with wrap_content in the GridLayout and RelativeLayouts and I removed the weights and it finally looks okay but not quite. Now there's a lot of empty space below the elements and you can still scroll down even tho there's nothing there. I tried changing layout_height to wrap content in the LinearLayout and the ScrollView but that doesn't solve it. Do you know what the problem might be?